# number of noun after no

Tags: grammatical-number

1. It is important to note that no legal **systems have** restricted men from touching household chores nor compelled women to do so.
2. It is important to note that no legal **system has** restricted men from touching household chores nor compelled women to do so.

what would be the number (singular or plural) of noun after 'no'?

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of nouns"?

Comment: @nmar - It looks to me like the OP is asking if the word _system_ should be pluralized to _systems_.

Answer (score 1):

For the "zero case," you can use either one. Either way of saying it would be grammatically correct.

In the case of "only one," you would need to use the singular:

> It is important to note that only one legal system has...

while in the case of "more than one," you would need to use the plural:

> It is important to note that only a few legal systems have...
>   It is important to note that many legal systems have...

One other thing to consider: if you are talking about throughout the course of human history, you can use "have restricted," and you might even add an "ever" for emphasis, as in:

> It is important to note that no legal systems have ever restricted...

whereas if you are only talking about the current time, you might omit the "have" altogether, and simply write:

> It is important to note that no legal systems restrict...

Comment: Thanks a lot particularly for the idea about using 'ever' which would be more appropriate for improving my writing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use both singular and plural nouns and verb forms after "no":

> [No man is an island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_man_is_an_island).
>
> I have no living cousins that I know about. ([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/no_1))

+

From *Oxford Living Grammar elementary*:

[image]

Comment: Another key point: That statement about hotels could be worded in the singular, too: _There is no hotel in this part of town._

Comment: @J.R. yes, sure.