# My house {have/has} no {windows/window}

Tags: sentence-construction

> My house have no windows.

I'm confused with two possible corrections:
1. have or has
2. windows or window

Comment: The *subject* of the verb ***to have*** is ***My house*** (a ***singular*** noun), so the verb form must ALWAYS be singular *My house **has...*** It's syntactically valid to follow that with negated singular OR plural *(no **window / windows**)* with no significant change in meaning, but plural is far more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for editing and your comment

Comment: Because you've effectively asked ***two*** questions at once *(my house **have** or **has**, no **window** or **windows**)*, I don't know if I can cite the earlier question [number of noun after no](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184618/number-of-noun-after-no) as a "duplicate". But it's certainly *related*.

Comment: Yes, Indeed. And what I have found from this link is it doesn't matter whether there should be singular or plural noun after the word "no"

Comment: I think there's a case for saying that the (idiomatically, less common) singular *(She has no **child**)* would often be seen as more *emphatic* than plural *(She has no **children**)*. I bit like the difference between *She doesn't have **a single one*** and *She doesn't have **any***. But that's a fine point, and may not always apply anyway.

Comment: Although *no window* is valid, you'd normally use the singular only if exactly one is expected: *My house has no garage, no kitchen, no basement.  Some ancient statues have no arms; some have no head.*  A house typically has many windows, so *no windows*.

Answer (score 3):

> **My house has no window**.
>
> **My house has no windows**.

I think the above two answers are correct.

**House** is singular so  it needs a singular  verb

The adjective **no** is followed by either singular or plural number.So window and windows are possible.But plural windows  sound natural.

Comment: "My house has no windows" would be much more common.  "My house has no window" makes it sound like you expect the house to have exactly one window.  Or in a dialog like this:

"I'm here in front of your house.  Look out your window."
"My house has no window."